# How to build a confusion matrix for a dataframe

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I have the following dataframe:

```
v1  v2  v3  v4  v5
0   t   1   12  N/A
1   t   0   34  N/A
2   t   1   45  N/A
5   f   0   76  N/A
12  f   0   98  N/A
45  t   1   45  M
```

I want to be able to construct the following confusion matrix on the two columns v2 and v3:

```
    t  |  f
 0  1     2
 1  3     0
```

What is the most elegant way to do this in R

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easily done with `table`...

```
table(df$v3,df$v2)

    f t
  0 2 1
  1 0 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `xtabs`. E.g., see this example

```
> set.seed(100)
> n <- 20
> x1 <- runif(n) > .5
> x2 <- ifelse(runif(n) > .75, x1, runif(n) > .5) 
> dat <- data.frame(x1, x2)
> head(dat)
     x1    x2
1 FALSE FALSE
2 FALSE  TRUE
3  TRUE  TRUE
4 FALSE  TRUE
5 FALSE  TRUE
6 FALSE FALSE
> xtabs(~ x1 + x2, dat)
       x2
x1      FALSE TRUE
  FALSE     9    3
  TRUE      3    5
```